# Where to report bug for ubuntu-desktop-next?

Tags: bug-reporting, 14.10, unity8

I'm testing daily build of ubuntu-desktop-next, and I found a bug that I want to report. For which package to report bug? Is there ubunut-desktop-next? I can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Searching on packages.ubuntu.com: common mistakes

There is a [ubuntu-desktop-next](http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/ubuntu-desktop-next) package. There are 2 possible reasons that could explained why you didn't find it:

- You might just mispelling while searching for it. Only interchanging two characters will suffice to not find the correct package. For example, as you mentioned in your question: `ubunut-desktop-next`
- You search it with the wrong version number. By default, the search is looking for packages in  the last current LTS version (trusty 14.04). Since the package is only available since utopic (14.10+), it didn't find it. But the search still warns you that it has found a package with this name but it can't currently be displayed:

  > Some results have not been displayed due to the search parameters.

Then the bug reports link is just taking you to the related project on Launchpad: [ubuntu-touch-meta](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-touch-meta/+bugs).

## Before reporting a bug

Since you've found a bug 2 weeks ago, don't forget to check:

- if someone didn't already file it
- if the new builds didn't already fixed it

Answer (score 0):

You should be using this !
[Launchpad](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Launchpad)

Comment: Yes, I know. I reported bugs earlier. But now I'm not sure for which package to report bug.